# Restkit 0.10.1 object mapping with RKObjectManager

Tags: objective-c, json, ios5, mapping, restkit

I have struggled so much to find a solution and a good tutorial that teach Object Mapping feature of Restkit.  However, the tutorial from the GITHUB repo is very unclear.

This the JSON I receive of making a GET call to http://baseURL.com/contacts/

Please notice that my JSON does not have a root keypath like "ACContact", compared to other tutorials.

```
[{
 "status":"ACTIVE",
 "fax":"555-1212",
"addresses":[
  {
     "line1":"6 Main Street",
     "line2":"",
     "city":"Acton"
  },
  {
     ...
  }
....(other stuff)...
}
...more similar JSONs for the other contacts...
]
```

I still cannot figure out how to map the array of children objects Addresses, thus I just try to map other regular property of the class:

```
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL: some_URL] ;

[[manager client] setValue:@"true" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SSLClientCipher"] ;
[[manager client] setValue:@"accept" forHTTPHeaderField:@"application/json"] ;

RKObjectMapping * contactMap = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ACContact class]] ;
[contactMap mapKeyPath:@"status" toAttribute:@"status"] ;
[contactMap mapKeyPath:@"fax" toAttribute:@"fax"] ;

[[manager mappingProvider] addObjectMapping:contactMap] ;

[manager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/contacts" delegate:self] ;
```

This is **the errors** I received afterward:

**restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMapper.m:81 Adding mapping error: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''**

**restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:222 Encountered errors during mapping: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''**

1)Can anyone please tell me what is going wrong here?
Please notice that my JSON does not have a root keypath like "ACContact", compared to other tutorials.

For simple attributes like status and fax in the JSON, is there a convention for mapping the values into my Contact class's properties.

2)Furthermore, I know I can use relation ship mapping to map the child objects Addresses, but how do I do it when I declare an NSMutableArray to store the list of addresses inside the contact.

3)If everything is ok, how is it possible to create a list of contacts when parsing the entire JSON of multiple Contacts?

Thank you for your time.
Brian

Answer (score 0):

For mapping to JSON without rootkeypath, we set  use:

[self.manager.mappingProvider setObjectMapping:self.contactMap forResourcePathPattern:@"/contacts"] ;

However, this pose a problem that you can't do a POST, because there is no wat to create serialization mapping for object without RootKeyPath.